# how can i set part of the view appear at its child view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

On the child view, I set the backgroundColor with a picture which have some transparent part.

```
[viewDown setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background_down.png"]]];
```

The transparent part don't have the parent view's background, but the black color instead.

How can i do for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `opaque` property to `NO`.

```
viewDown.opaque = NO;
```